# React Router Link Not Rendering the Component but changes the URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
               <Router>
                <Fragment>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact  path="/" component={Landing}/>
                        <Route   path="/developer/register/" component={RegisterDev} />
                        <Route   path="/developer/login/" component={LoginDev} />
                        <Route   path="/developer/dashboard/" component={Landing} />
                        <Route   path="/agency/register/" component={RegisterAgency} />
                        <Route   path="/agency/login/" component={LoginAgency} />

                        <Route component={NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                </Fragment>
            </Router>
```

in My NavBar Component

```
//NavBar.js
<Link to="/"  Home > </Link>
```

The Problem is when I am in /developer/register or /developer/login component, if I click on Home Link, the URL Changes but not rendering the Landing component. 
All other components are working fine with Link. Only problem with Link Home to /. I tried withRouter, , Still the URL changes to / but the Landing component not rendering unless I refresh.

For now I am using href / to escape this problem but I want to understand why with Link its not rendering.

Comment: can you share your code in sandbox

Comment: nothing looks to be off. Do you get any console errors. are there are router related code surrounding this or in the parent component ?

Comment: console is clear. It is happening only with '/'. All other component navigations are working fine. Like /developer/login to /developer/register. But from /developer/register or any other component to '/" changes the URL, but Landing component is not loading. For now I am <a href="/> instead of Link to="/"

Comment: please share a sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I should have shared my Landing page component in the question. I am using some jquery slider in my Landing component. I suppose react routing will not load the page as everything here is virtual DOM. The reason it was working with href because it is reloading the entire home page.

With little research I found [LoadJS Package](https://github.com/muicss/loadjs)

Now I can load jquery slider scripts with load js and my Link to / is working fine without a problem. Thanks everyone who commented and responded . I should have posted Landing Page Component.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding exact in the route path.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
               <Router>
                <Fragment>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact  path="/" component={Landing}/>
                        <Route exact   path="/developer/register/" component={RegisterDev} />
                        <Route exact   path="/developer/login/" component={LoginDev} />
                        <Route exact   path="/developer/dashboard/" component={Landing} />
                        <Route exact   path="/agency/register/" component={RegisterAgency} />
                        <Route exact   path="/agency/login/" component={LoginAgency} />

                        <Route component={NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                </Fragment>
            </Router>
```

Comment: I tried this already. No Use. I am guessing there is something to do with Switch. Also tried DebugRouter, the console log paths are fine but its not rendering the component for /

Comment: Take this line out of Switch and also comment NotFound Route.

<Route   path="/" component={Landing}/>
It works in above scenarios, but the problem is it loads landing page along with every other route. But Link to / works if I place this out of switch. If I push inside to Switch, The Component doesnt render

Comment: I suppose you have `historyApiFallback` set as true in your webpack dev server config. Have you set that already?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to="/"  Home > </Link>
```

What syntax is this?

Either you are trying to print Home as a label in which case it should be

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
```

or you are trying to make this as part of your route in which case it should be

`<Link to="/Home"/>`  (Here there won't be a display text though)

Please check your syntax for [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) where you are using Link and provide a sandbox if it still doesn't work.